# Are there an infinite or finite number of colors (can we see infinity?)

Tags: visible-light, vision, biology, perception

Take any blue or red, mix in equal parts and you have purple. Now mix 50 units of red and add 25 units of blue for another purple, then 50 units of red and 12.5 units of blue for yet another purple ect... so you can halve the blue into infinity for an infinite number of color combinations. I see in a similar question that the eye may not be able to distinguish all combinations, so:

an infinite number of combinations but a finite number of colors

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about the biology of color perception, not about physics.

Comment: We model color space as a [_continuum_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics). That's subtly different from "an infinite number of..." It's the difference between a [_countable set_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) and an [_uncountable set_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set).

Comment: A better question (for you to ask, but not necessarily a better question for this site) is, "how many different colors can an average human _distinguish_?" There can be an infinity of different colors that are all too close to each other for you to be able to see any difference between them.

Comment: the number of colors we perceive is  finite

Answer (score 3):

Human eyes have 3 different color receptors(RGB), each of which is more sensitive to some frequencies than others. There are an infinite number of colors, but there are limits as to how a person can distinguish between different intensities coming from each type of photoreceptor.

Well if you neglect the imperfections of the human eyes, there are of course continuously many colors. Each frequency in the visible spectrum gives a different color. However, these colors given by a unique frequency are just "monochromatic" colors. We may also combine different frequencies – which is something totally different than adding the frequencies or taking the average of frequencies. In this, there are $∞^∞$ colors of light. Of course there are limitations to the lower and upper limits of frequencies as you might know.

Comment: Good answer, but $\infty^\infty$ isn't meaningful. What you aim for is the cardinality of the set of functions from wavelength to intensity, which is $\beth_2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum It is likely easier to say "uncountably infinite" and leave it there.

Comment: @AndersSandberg yeah, I know it isn't meaningful. Sorry!